# UpdateCursor increment reference in initial layer with ArcPy dosen't work

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I use a function to increment the reference according to a condition I would like to update the reference in the initial table I do it with the following code but the line for the update doesn't seem to work since the reference remains the same in the layer.

How can I update the incremented reference in the initial layer ax_chamber?

```
pattern_poteaux = r"(POT|PHT)+[-]+[0-9]{5}[-]+[a-zA-Z]{2}[-][0-9]*"
pattern_chambre = r"CHB+[-]+[0-9]+[-]+[a-zA-Z]{2}[-]+[0-9]*"

"""
@param :
1: pattern regex
2: string
return Booleen si la référence est valide
"""
def attribute_check(pattern, sample_str):
    if re.search(pattern, sample_str) is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False

"""
@param: chaine de caractère
return : incrémente la référence de 1 
"""
reference_incrementee = []
reference_invalide = []
def increment_ref(pattern, sample_str):
    if attribute_check(pattern, sample_str) == True:
        reference_incrementee.append(sample_str)
        return re.sub(r'[^-]+[0-9]$', lambda x: str(int(x.group()) + 1).zfill(len(x.group())), sample_str)   
    else:
      reference_invalide.append(sample_str)

AX_CHAMBER = r'\OSP_LOADER.mdb\AX_CHAMBER'
CHAMB = r'\OSP_LOADER.mdb\CHAMBER'
DicorefCh={}
fcc1=['REFERENCE', 'OBJECTID', "SHAPE@XY", "CODE_SITE" ]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(CHAMB,fcc1) as c:
     for row1 in c:
         DicorefCh[row1[0]]=[row1[1],row1[2], row1[3]]
del c
DicorefCh2={}
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(AX_CHAMBER,fcc2) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         DicorefCh2[row[0]]=[row[2], row[12]]
del cursor 
fcc2=["REFERENCE", "EXIST", "INTER", "RESUL", "OBJECTID", "SHAPE@XY","CODE_SITE"]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(AX_CHAMBER,fcc2) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         row[2]=0
         cursor.updateRow(row)
         score=int(row[1])+int(row[2])
         if (score==1) and row[4] in doubref:
             idND=DicorefCh[DicorefCh2[row[4]]]
             d=math.sqrt((idND[1][0]-row[5][0])**2+(idND[1][1]-row[5][1])**2)
             ax_code_site = row[7]
             ref_ax_chambre = row[0]
         if d > 50.0 and idND[2] != ref_ax_chambre :
               result = increment_ref(pattern_chambre, ref_ax_chambre)
               ref_ax_chamre = result
               cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image: I woud like to replace the result by the result who is equal to POT-16175-FT-2239]

Comment: @amaranaitsaidi, how is this any different from the question you asked two days ago (see Hornbydd comment)?  And I noticed you posted some of this same code on SO ( [compare two fields in dictionnary python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71924408/compare-two-fields-in-dictionnary-python)) two days ago.

Comment: I rephrased the question to make it clearer, they are two different problems the first one was to compare the second one was to update a field.

Comment: It is better to update the original question to clarify it than to start a new one asking the same thing in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the REFERENCE (index position 0) before you update the cursor.
The final lines should read like this:

```
if d > 50.0 and idND[2] != ref_ax_chambre:
    result = increment_ref(pattern_chambre, ref_ax_chambre)
    row[0] = result
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

That said you have some fundamental issues with the code you posted.
fcc2 is not defined before you use it here:

```
    DicorefCh2={}
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(AX_CHAMBER,fcc2) as cursor:
         for row in cursor:
             DicorefCh2[row[0]]=[row[2], row[12]]
```

It can be a search cursor at this point.
If ffc2 is the same as the ffc2 that is defined later, row[12] doesn't exist as you have only defined 7 fields.
ax_code_site = row[7] will also fail as fields are indexed from Zero.